# Efficient way to search an element

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, search

Recently I had an interview, where they asked me a "*searching*" question.
The question was:

> Assume there is an array of (positive) integers, of which each element is either `+1` or `-1` compared to its adjacent elements.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> array = [4,5,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
> ```
>
> Now search for `7` and return its position.

I gave this answer:

> Store the values in a temporary array, sort them, and then apply binary search.
>
> If the element is found, return its position in the temporary array.
>   (If the number is occurring twice then return its first occurrence)

But, they didn't seem to be satisfied with this answer.

What is the right answer?

Comment: As far as I know, a linear search is a good way to locate the index of an element in the array. I'm not sure yet of another searching algorithm that is efficient in locating the index of an element.

Comment: in linear search i have to traverse each and every element...is their any pattern or something else...because i have to minimize the complexity

Comment: So far, I'd suggest linear search.

Comment: If 7 is guaranteed to only appear once or if it doesn't matter which 7 is returned you can improve some more on the linear algorithm of coleman's answer.

Comment: If your original solution requires sorting, it's worse than the naive linear search. You seem to be not aware of that.

Comment: Sorting requires O(nlogn), and a binary search is O(logn). If you need to search many many values from the large array, your answer may be better, but if you only to search once, O(n) algorithms may be better.

Comment: Was there an additional requirement on the input data that the element to be searched for was larger than the first thing in the array and smaller than the last thing in the array?

Comment: @PaulHankin No..their is no such requirements...no such condition...Only I have array and the value need to be searched

Comment: @RahulMishra you didn't like linear search because you didn't like that it had to traverse each and every element, so you proposed 1) copy into a temporary array, then 2) sort the temporary array. do you see the problem with that?

Comment: Here's a bit of advice from my experience interviewing.  When asked these kinds of questions, the desired solution rarely involves sorting the inputs.

Comment: @user2023861 thanks for you suggestion..I will always keep this in my mind :)

Comment: I don’t know why no one else has mentioned this: your method was not only inefficient, it was **incorrect**, and that’s much worse than mere inefficiency. The requirement is for the position of a given number *in the original array*. Your method returns the position of the number *in a sorted array*. Now, you *could* retrieve the original position, by converting the simple array to an array of tuples (number, orig_pos) before sorting. But you didn’t mention that, so I’m guessing you didn’t mention it in the interview, either.

Comment: The problem specification includes the detail that each element of the array is either +1 or -1 its preceding element. Although it's possible they threw that in as a red herring, it seems like it was intended to help you create a more efficient algorithm than a normal search. The fact that your algorithm doesn't take advantage of this is likely why they immediately failed you.

Comment: Is there an practical application of this search? I am just curious.

Comment: @RSahu This kind of data arises in martingales, random walks and brownian motion.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can do a linear search with steps that are often greater than 1. The crucial observation is that if e.g. `array[i] == 4` and 7 hasn't yet appeared then the next candidate for 7 is at index `i+3`. Use a while loop which repeatedly goes directly to the next viable candidate.

Here is an implementation, slightly generalized. It finds the first occurrence of `k` in the array (subject to the +=1 restriction) or `-1` if it doesn't occur:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int first_occurence(int k, int array[], int n);

int main(void){
    int a[] = {4,3,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,8,7,8};
    printf("7 first occurs at index %d\n",first_occurence(7,a,15));
    printf("but 9 first \"occurs\" at index %d\n",first_occurence(9,a,15));
    return 0;
}

int first_occurence(int k, int array[], int n){
    int i = 0;
    while(i < n){
        if(array[i] == k) return i;
        i += abs(k-array[i]);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

output:

```
7 first occurs at index 11
but 9 first "occurs" at index -1
```

Comment: Precisely what I was thinking. This is `O(N)`, but I don't think there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: You could do it a bit faster on average with more candidates (e.g. first and last), and then going with the one that's closest to the target - that is if you only need to find a single occurrence, not the first one.

Comment: @mkadunc That is a good idea. Another observation is that if the first and last elements straddle 7 then in that special case you can use a binary search (if you don't care which 7 you find)

Comment: In the case where you need to find any 7 (not necessarily the first one), I propose the following (practical) improvement. Make a list of sections (two integers, 'start' and 'end') and instead of starting at the beginning of the array, start in the middle. According to the value in the cell ignore relevant range and add the two left over sections to your list of sections. Now repeat for next item in the list. This is still 'O(n)', but you're ignore twice the range every time you check a cell.

Comment: @ShapiroYaacov : Combined with checking if the interval from the lower to the higher of the values to both sides of a section includes k(7), this deserves an answer of its own.

Comment: @greybeard, what is k(7)?

Comment: @ShapiroYaacov : `k` is what John Coleman called the integer sought (for _key_?), `7` is the unadorned digit literal from the question.

Comment: Do you need `#include <math.h>` ?  On my system, and based on SVr4, POSIX.1-2001, 4.3BSD, C99 standards `abs()` is defined in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: @arielf You are correct. I've been doing mostly Python programming recently and forgot which header file to include for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 35):

Your approach is too complicated. You don't need to examine every array element. The first value is `4`, so `7` is *at least* `7-4` elements away, and you can skip those.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int array[] = {4,5,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int len = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];
    int i = 0;
    int steps = 0;
    while (i < len && array[i] != 7) {
        i += abs(7 - array[i]);
        steps++;
    }
    
    printf("Steps %d, index %d\n", steps, i);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
Steps 4, index 11
```

Edit: improved after comments from @Martin Zabel.

Comment: You should set `skip` to the absolute difference between 7 and `array[i]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane this has the assumption that the element is always found in the array, which might not be the case. -1 is a valid return in that case; which changes the code you have quite a bit

Comment: @Eugene if not found, `i >= len`

Answer (score 20):

A variation of the conventional linear search could be a good way to go. Let us pick an element say `array[i] = 2`. Now, `array[i + 1]` will either be 1 or 3 (odd), `array[i + 2]` will be (positive integers only) 2 or 4 (even number).

On continuing like this, a pattern is observable - `array[i + 2*n]` will hold even numbers and so all these indices can be ignored.

Also, we can see that

```
array[i + 3] = 1 or 3 or 5
array[i + 5] = 1 or 3 or 5 or 7
```

so, index `i + 5` should be checked next and a while loop can be used to determine the next index to check, depending on the value found at index `i + 5`.

While, this has complexity `O(n)` (linear time in terms of asymptotic complexity), it is better than a normal linear search in practical terms as all the indices are not visited.

Obviously, all this will be reversed if `array[i]` (our starting point) was odd.

Answer (score 8):

The approach presented by John Coleman is what the interviewer was hoping for, in all probability.
If you are willing to go quite a bit more complicated, you can increase expected skip length:
Call the target value *k*. Start with the first element's value *v* at position *p* and call the difference k-v *dv* with  absolute value *av*. To speed negative searches, have a peek at the last element as the other value *u* at position *o*: if dv×du is negative, k is present (if any occurrence of k is acceptable, you may narrow down the index range here the way binary search does). If av+au is greater than the length of the array, k is absent. (If dv×du is zero, v or u equals k.)
Omitting index validity: Probe the ("next") position where the sequence might return to v with k in the middle: `o = p + 2*av`.
If dv×du is negative, find k (recursively?) from p+av to o-au;
if it is zero, u equals k at o.
If du equals dv and the value in the middle isn't k, or au exceeds av,
or you *fail* to find k from p+av to o-au,
let `p=o; dv=du; av=au;` and keep probing.
(For a full flash-back to '60ies texts, view with Courier. My "1st 2nd thought" was to use `o = p + 2*av - 1`, which precludes *du equals dv*.)

Answer (score 4):

**STEP 1**

Start with the first element and check if it's 7. Let's say `c` is the index of the current position. So, initially,  `c = 0`.

**STEP 2**

If it is 7, you found the index. It's `c`. If you've reached the end of the array, break out.

**STEP 3**

If it's not, then 7 must be atleast `|array[c]-7|` positions away because you can only add a unit per index. Therefore, Add `|array[c]-7|` to your current index, c, and go to STEP 2 again to check.

In the worst case, when there are alternate 1 and -1s, the time complexity may reach O(n), but average cases would be delivered quickly.

Comment: How is this different from John Coleman's answer? (Apart from suggesting `|c-7|` where  `|array[c]-7|` seems called for.)

Comment: I just saw his answer. I admit that the core idea is same.

Comment: The original question doesn't stipulate that the array starts with a number smaller than 7. So `array[c]-7` may be positive or negative.  You need to apply `abs()` to it before the skip forward.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That's why I'm using `array[c] - 7` with the modulus operator, `|array[c] - 7|`.

Answer (score 4):

Here I am giving the implementation in java...

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
    int arr[]={4,5,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    int pos=searchArray(arr,7);

    if(pos==-1)
        System.out.println("not found");
    else
        System.out.println("position="+pos);            
}

public static int searchArray(int[] array,int value)
{
    int i=0;
    int strtValue=0;
    int pos=-1;

    while(i<array.length)
    {
        strtValue=array[i];

        if(strtValue<value)
        {
            i+=value-strtValue;
        }
        else if (strtValue==value)
        {
            pos=i;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            i=i+(strtValue-value);
        }       
    }

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Undocumented code in a language with an at least [semi-official convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#styleguide). How is this different from the answers of John Coleman and Akeshwar, other than interpreting the tag "c" liberally?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a divide-and-conquer style solution. At the expense of (much) more bookkeeping, we can skip more elements; rather than scanning left-to-right, test in the middle and skip in *both* directions.

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                               
#include <math.h>                                                                

int could_contain(int k, int left, int right, int width);                        
int find(int k, int array[], int lower, int upper);   

int main(void){                                                                  
    int a[] = {4,3,2,3,2,3,4,5,4,5,6,7,8,7,8};                                   
    printf("7 first occurs at index %d\n",find(7,a,0,14));                       
    printf("but 9 first \"occurs\" at index %d\n",find(9,a,0,14));               
    return 0;                                                                    
}                                                                                

int could_contain(int k, int left, int right, int width){                        
  return (width >= 0) &&                                                         
         (left <= k && k <= right) ||                                            
         (right <= k && k <= left) ||                                            
         (abs(k - left) + abs(k - right) < width);                               
}                                                                                

int find(int k, int array[], int lower, int upper){                              
  //printf("%d\t%d\n", lower, upper);                                            

  if( !could_contain(k, array[lower], array[upper], upper - lower )) return -1;  

  int mid = (upper + lower) / 2;                                                 

  if(array[mid] == k) return mid;                                                

  lower = find(k, array, lower + abs(k - array[lower]), mid - abs(k - array[mid]));
  if(lower >= 0 ) return lower;                                                    

  upper = find(k, array, mid + abs(k - array[mid]), upper - abs(k - array[upper]));
  if(upper >= 0 ) return upper;                                                  

  return -1;                                                                     

}
```

Comment: neal-fultz your answer won't return the first occurrence but any random occurrence of the search element as you are starting from middle and skipping from either side.

Comment: Switching the order of recursion is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: neal-fultz then please edit the message in your printf() method call.

Answer (score 2):

```
const findMeAnElementsFunkyArray = (arr, ele, i) => {
  const elementAtCurrentIndex = arr[i];

  const differenceBetweenEleAndEleAtIndex = Math.abs(
    ele - elementAtCurrentIndex
  );

  const hop = i + differenceBetweenEleAndEleAtIndex;

  if (i >= arr.length) {
    return;
  }
  if (arr[i] === ele) {
    return i;
  }

  const result = findMeAnElementsFunkyArray(arr, ele, hop);

  return result;
};

const array = [4,5,6,5,4,3,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

const answer = findMeAnElementsFunkyArray(array, 7, 0);

console.log(answer);
```

Wanted to include a recursive solution to the problem. Enjoy